# dbms_output.put_line doesn't work inside function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I expect the following code to print 'abc' before returning 1.

Even though I ran `set serveroutput on`, it still doesn't print anything.

If, instead of a function, it would be a procedure, it would work.

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (
    code NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
    IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('abc');
    RETURN 1;
END;

SELECT
    test(30)
FROM
    dual;
```

Comment: The general answer to this is using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()`. What business reason do you have for executing this? There's almost never a need for this in production code.

Comment: Which client are you using? How are you executing the query? If it's SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer and you're running it as a script, it should just work. If you're running the query as a statement - so the function return value goes in a 'Query Result' window - have you got the 'Dbms Output' window open (from the View menu)? Do you see the `abc` message after you run a `commit`?

Comment: Works for me in SQL*Plus and PL/SQL Developer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using SQL Developer, you should add the

> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

before calling the function.

and then, execute the function using F5 (Run Script) instead of F9(Run Statement). The difference betwen these 2 modes to execute a sentence is the mode of displayng the result.
F5 displays the result as like a PLSQL code
F9 displays the result as like a SQL code. On this way, you will see only the result of the SQL.

Here is the output using the F5 mode:

> ### TEST(30)
>
> ```
>      1
> ```
>
> abc

other wise, you should include the select statement into a PL_SQL anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a SQL statement doesn't always flush the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer; that'll depend in part on the execution environment/tool.

You can be pretty darn sure to see the output if you put the query inside a block as in:

```
DECLARE
   i NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT test(30) INTO i
     FROM dual;
END;
```